# AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I inherited a project that was originally developed on another developer's machine in VS2008 with AjaxControlToolkit (3.0.20820.16598 runtime version v2.0.50727).  I converted the project in VS2010 on my machine to target .Net Framework 4.0.  Now none of the AjaxControlToolkit controls on the pages works.  However, the project is still compiled without errors.  Does anyone know what to do to get those controls from AjaxControlkit working?  I downloaded the V4.1.5116 and referenced it in the converted project.  It didn't work.  I also tried converting the project to target .Net Framework 3.5 and using the V3.5.5116 Ajax Controls and referenced it in the project.  It didn't work either.

Comment: Try re-installing it using NuGet, that helped me.Also make sure you converted project to work with 4.0 framework.

Comment: I used NuGet to reinstalled the ACT.  That didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I accidentally use  instead of <%-- --%> to comment out some ACT controls. The Ajax Controls between the html comment tag are still rendered by the server. When interact with other ACT controls, it generates script errors and prevents the rest of script from working.